# Remove "<" from UINavigationItem Back Button

Tags: ios, swift, uibarbuttonitem

How can I remove the "<" from the UINavigationItem Back Button.  I have a UIViewController on my storyboard that's opened with a Push segue.  I'd like to just have the text on the back button, and not the back arrow.

So far, I added this code to the prepareForSegue function in the calling UITableViewController.

```
        let backItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle., target: nil, action: nil)
        navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = backItem
```

When the UIView comes up, it has "< Done" in the text of the back button.  How can I set it up so that it just has "Done"?

Comment: set leftbar button instead of backbutton

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Add this 2 line of code in your appdelegate. It will remove back indicator from all the view controllers.

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

    UINavigationBar.appearance().backIndicatorImage = UIImage()
    UINavigationBar.appearance().backIndicatorTransitionMaskImage = UIImage()

}
```

If you are getting space in left side then set title position

```
UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setBackButtonTitlePositionAdjustment(UIOffsetMake(-20, 0), for: UIBarMetrics.default)
```

Comment: That did remove the "<".  Is there any way to reclaim the space that is left behind?  My button text occupies the same space as it did when the "<" was displaying, and that leaves a pretty good sized space to the left of the button text.

Comment: Yes, that is perfect!  Thank you so much.

Comment: @ScottKilbourn Welcome anytime :)

Comment: I'm trying to use this with iOS 13 but it doesn't seem to work. Do you have any clues?I have tried putting the code in both the parent and child view controller

Answer (score 2):

In `viewDidLoad`

```
self.navigationItem.setHidesBackButton(true, animated: false)
```

If you have a custom `UINavigationBar` set `leftBarButtonItem` to `nil`

Comment: I put the self.navigationItem.setHidesBackButton line in the viewDidLoad of the opening UIViewController.  Now the button is completely gone.

Comment: @ScottKilbourn old response.... but that's not a problem. You can add a left button in the navigationbar in the view controller using `self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem` just like the right one. I actually would recommend using this method since it gives you more control of assigning the left and right buttons rather than hiding just the chevron globally via Appdelegate.